# Implemented FastApi auto documentation behind authentication, but only the authentication endpoints are being documented

Tags: python, fastapi, swagger-ui, fastapiusers

I implemented my endpoints documentation behind authentication using basic auth, based on @EasonC13 in the link, only using two other functions to query my database and other one to compare password tokens.

https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/8169

When everything goes fine and i get the answer from the endpoint, it doesn't give me the documentation for my endpoints, instead it gives documentation for the new 2 endpoints for the documentation authentication.

Here is the code:

Main code file:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

from routers import cliente, produto, faturaVenda, autoDocumentation

app = FastAPI(docs_url=None, redoc_url=None, openapi_url=None)

app.include_router(cliente.router)
app.include_router(produto.router)
app.include_router(faturaVenda.router)
app.include_router(autoDocumentation.router)

@app.get("/test", tags=["Hello World"])
def hello_world() -> None:
    return {"Hello my first FastAPI api"}
```

The endpoints for the documentation based on authentication:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, "/Users/user/Desktop/Api")

from fastapi.openapi.docs import get_swagger_ui_html
from fastapi.openapi.utils import get_openapi
from authentication.autoDocumentationAuthentication import check_entity_credencials
from fastapi import Depends, APIRouter

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/docs")
async def get_documentation(username: str = Depends(check_entity_credencials)):
    return get_swagger_ui_html(openapi_url="/openapi.json", title="docs")


@router.get("/openapi.json")
async def openapi(username: str = Depends(check_entity_credencials)):
    return get_openapi(title = "FastAPI", version="0.1.0", routes=router.routes)
```

The function check_entity_credencials is where the basic auth logic is stored, here's it:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, "/Users/user/Desktop/project/Api")

from fastapi.security import HTTPBasicCredentials, HTTPBasic
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status
from repository.configuration.databaseConfigurationAndQuery import DatabaseConnectorAndQuery
from utils.hasher import hashString, verifyHash

security = HTTPBasic()

def check_entity_credencials(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security)):    
    correctEntityId = check_entity_id_in_db(credentials.username)
    
    correct_password = check_entity_password_in_db(correctEntityId)
            
    if correctEntityId != None and correct_password != None:
        if verifyHash(credentials.password, correct_password):
            return credentials.username
        else: 
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                detail="Password or ID passed is incorrect",
                headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Basic"},
            )
```

Before implementing the documentation behing authentication, the '/doc' would return:

- endpoint 1
- endpoint 2
- endpoint 3
- ...

Then after implementing the authentication:

- getdocumentation
- openapi

Any hints on a way to return auto documentation page with my actuall api's like the one it was returning as default?

Comment: In your `openapi` function you're only passing `router.routes` i.e. only the routes registered to that specific router. You need to pass it `app.routes`, i.e. the whole application's routes. (This might mean that you have to move those two endpoints to the same file where `app` is defined to avoid circular imports).

Comment: Happy to help :)